# A question obout the sum of series in $[-\infty,+\infty]$

Tags: solution-verification

Suppose that the work set is $[-\infty+\infty]$, we suppose that $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n<+\infty.$$ Now can we says that $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(a_n-b_n)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} b_n\quad$$

In the $[-\infty,+\infty]$ each series(well defined) converges, therefore for me is yes. It's true?

Comment: Is the convergence of $\sum b_n$ part of your hypothesis?

Comment: No that's just a well-defined series

Comment: So if you take something like $a_n = 0$ and $b_n = (-1)^n$, that would satisfy your conditions? So then your equality is in the sense that both sides are divergent. Is that fine with you? (As in, would you still consider that the equality holds in this case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = -\infty$, then the result need not hold. Consider the counterexample:
$$a_n = -1, b_n = -1.$$

If we assume further that $-\infty < \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, then it does hold (in a reasonable sense) as I shall show now.

---

Let $S_N = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N a_n - b_n,$ $A_N = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N a_n,$ and $B_N = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N b_n.$

You wish to answer whether the equality
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}S_N = \lim_{N \to \infty}A_N - \lim_{N \to \infty}B_N$$
holds.

---

Clearly, we have $S_n = A_n - B_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.
The convergence of $(A_n)$ (to a real number) is part of the hypothesis.

If $(B_n)$ converges to a real number, then it follows that your desired equality holds.

If $(B_n)$ converges to $-\infty$, then the RHS is $\infty$. Moreover, we can bound $A_n$ and thus, it is easy to show that $S_n \to \infty$ as well. Thus, the equality holds again.
The same consideration applies to the case $B_n \to \infty$.

Now, let us consider the case that $(B_n)$ diverges (that is, not converges). In this case, we have that the RHS is not defined.
We show that the LHS isn't defined either. That is, show that $(S_n)$ diverges as well.
Note that 
$$B_n = A_n - S_n \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N.$$
If $(S_n)$ were convergent, then $(A_n - S_n)$ would be as well and in turn, so would $B_n$. This gives us a contradiction and thus, we see that $(S_n)$ is divergent.

---

Thus, we conclude as follows:
Equality does hold in the following sense:

One side of the equality is defined if and only if the other is. Moreover, whenever both sides are defined, they are equal.

Comment: Therefore if $\{b_n\} \subseteq [0,+\infty]$ the equality holds?

Comment: Yes. Then you would have $B_n$ converges (possibly to $\infty$) and the result will hold even without the additional hypothesis that $A_n \not\to -\infty$.